# Result from command bash

Tags: git, bash, github, latex, raspberry-pi

I currently have a bash script that runs every night at 2:30 AM to render some LaTex files, which then get pushed up to a GitHub repo. As of now, even if no changes have occured (no new commits), the PDFs are generated, which is rather useless. The script that I have right now is this:

```
#!/bin/bash
{
    PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2014/bin/armhf-linux:$PATH
    cd /home/pi/Documents/Analysis-Notes/
    git pull #update all the data
    cd Scripts

    ./BuildAll.sh
    ./BuildChapterByChapter.sh


    cd /home/pi/Documents/Analysis-Notes/
    git add -A #Add all of the modified files to the commit


    git commit -m 'Generated New PDFs'

    git push


} || {
    echo -e "\n\n!!!! ERROR GENERATING FILES AUTOMATICALLY !!!!\n\n"
}
```

My question is: Is there any way to see what the response from the `git pull` command is, and then put an if statement (simple string comparison) which generates the files only if there has been a change??

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is the output of git-pull when there is & and when there isn't any new file ? You could do a grep on the output to determine the status of your comand

Comment: Use `make`, which already has all the logic to only run a command if one or more of its dependencies have been updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I kinda don't get what is the big deal about it?

```
if [[ $(git pull) != 'Already up-to-date.' ]]; then
    # do everything
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a number of options.

1. Use a tool like `make` which will only rebuild files that need rebuilding?
2. Use `git fetch` to pull the updated references and then compare the local branch ref with the remote branch ref.
3. Save the current revision before the pull and compare it against the current revision after the pull.